# PopScope to not trigger on flutter navigation

Tags: flutter

I don't want `onPopInvoked` to get triggered when I use `Navigator.pop(context)`

```dart
PopScope(
      canPop: false,
      onPopInvoked: (p) {
        log("POP $p"); <-- triggered for both system back press and Navigator.pop()
      },
```

Before I used to use `WillPopScope` but since it is going to be deprecated I was migrating to `PopScope`

```dart
 WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        log("POP $p"); <-- triggered only on system back press
        return true;
      },
```